# Draw an Image beside an Edit text in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I want to draw an image on the left of an EditText. I don't want the image appear insde the EditText though.

I use this:

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstNameTxt"
    style="@style/UserInfoInputs"
    android:drawablePadding="20dp"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/first_name" >
</EditText>
```

It displays the image inside of the EditText. However I use this on TextView and it works fine:

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/positionValue"
    style="@style/userInfo"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/position" />
```

How this can be done for an EditText?

Comment: Is there any reason you don't want to use a seperate <ImageView> control besides the EditText?

Comment: According to the Android Lint setting the drawable in the <EditText> is faster than adding another view. It will actually warn you that you can save a view by doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

          <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/go_image"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:src="@drawable/icon"
        />
        <EditText  
        android:id="@+id/url" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"     
        android:lines="1"
        android:layout_weight="1.0" />



    </LinearLayout>
```

let me know if this works.

Answer (score 1):

The difference between the two use-cases you describe are simple. There is no difference. With an EditText, there are lines that are easily discernible. With a TextView there is not. Try setting the background property of the textview, and you'll see that the drawable is, in fact, drawn on the left side, but still 'inside', the TextView.

The simplest way to accomplish your task (as described) is to utilize an ImageView. Depending on what ViewGroup (LinearLayout, RelativeLayout, etc) you're using, the code may be a bit different; so, update your question with the appropriate info and I'll make my answer a bit more specific.

I should note that, another method you could use is to create your own custom component, which is really very easy to do. See this article [Custom Components | Android Developer](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html), be sure to scroll down to the Compound Controls heading title "Compound Controls". This would be especially helpful when this is a 'common' format of controls that you'll use often (I.E. you have an image next to a TextView throughout your app).

Answer (score 0):

That is because the background part of the `EditText` stretches behind the entire contents of the view, *including the drawables*.
If you are using a `RelativeLayout` you can just add a separate `ImageView`:

```
<ImageView
    layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout_height="wrap_content"
    layout_toLeftOf="@+id/firstNameTxt"
    src="@drawable/first_name"
    other imageview attributes as neccessary...
    />
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/firstNameTxt"
    style="@style/UserInfoInputs"
    />
```

Or if you use another kind of layout, create a `LinearLayout`-wrapper:

```
<LinearLayout
    layout_width="wrap_content"
    layout_height="wrap_content">
    <ImageView
        layout_width="wrap_content"
        layout_height="wrap_content"
        layout_toLeftOf="@+id/firstNameTxt"
        src="@drawable/first_name"
        other imageview attributes as neccessary...
        />
    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/firstNameTxt"
        style="@style/UserInfoInputs"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```